# Android Studio recognises device, but not able to run code

Tags: android-studio

I am using an old smartphone as a device to run my app on in Android Studio. I recently switched to a new computer, so I reinstalled AS on that computer according to the docs. Android Studio recognises my device, but I'm nota ble to run my (Flutter) app on it, and the name of the device is marked with a small green dot.
[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if that was the problem causing this, but AS said that my Dart SDK was not installed. After installing and restarting, I was able to use a device to run my Flutter app.

Comment: Try also Qt Creator und the Qt library. It's a bit tricky to get it run but in the end you can use the Qt library for cool coding of Android apps. Qt comes with a lot of example projects for several Android apps.